# Magento 2: Update More Information panel attributes on click over a configuration

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, upgrade

Good evening,

I just installed Magento 2 with the Luma theme.
I created a configurable product and 4 configurations (4 simple products) and **I updated some simple products' atributes**.

On the frontend - in the configurable product page - **I was expecting the *More Information* panel to reload the attributes when I clicked on the configuration swatch, but nothing changed except the product image.**

Is that normal?
What can I do to reload all the attributes data?
I'm just doing some tests now so I would not touch the code if possible..

Thanks a lot,
Davide

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this free Amasty extension:

**Color Swatches Pro for Magento 2**

https://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro-for-magento-2.html